# Admin-only access to spring security ui controllers in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I would like to restrict access only for ROLE_ADMIN users to all controllers introduced by the Spring Security UI plugin in grails. (I am using grails 1.3.7, plugins.spring-security-core=1.1.3 and plugins.spring-security-ui=0.1.2)

I can run the config script and create a blank controller for each of the various controllers the ui plugin defines, and decorate that blank controller with `@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])`, but that seems like a tedious and unnecessary approach. Is there a better way?

Thanks,

Gene

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using annotations, the easiest way is to use the `controllerAnnotations.staticRules` config option. This is for static resources and controllers like these where you shouldn't edit them (or jump through hoops to secure them).

See section "5.1 Defining Secured Annotations" in http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Any reason why these controllers aren't decorated with ROLE_ADMIN by default? (or by global declaration?) Also, for others reading this answer, the `controllerAnnotations.staticRules` declaration goes in the config file, not in UrlMappings.

Comment: I didn't guard them by default because I don't know how they'll be used (or what role(s) will be allowed), and it's simple to set the Config.groovy property or use database Requestmaps.